# What mean `(value, value)` in JS obfluscated code

Tags: javascript

I try to understand how JS code works, but to the end I'm not sure what to look for. I have:

```
m = ((146.8E1, 67.60E1) > (71., 4.80E1) ? (0x5C, 'n') : (40., 83.))
```

The full expression is `if()`, but I don't know how to understand `(arg1, arg2)`.

My browsers (ff, chrome, edge) always returns 2 "arguments". 
It's just a method of onfluscate or syntax I don't know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [comma operator separates expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). `(a, b)` simply evaluates to `b`.

```
(a, b) > (c, d) ? (e, f) : (g, h)
```

is equivalent to

```
b > d ? f : g
```

Comment: But why is evaluates  to `b`?

Comment: @bato3 Because that's what it does.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I do not think correctly. I was looking for a too complicated explanation. And I forgot that I often use similar syntax.